# Finding most populated cities per country

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to write code that gives the most populated cities per country with the population.
Here is a input data:

```
DataFrame = {
/** Input data */
val inputDf = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", "Poland", "1 764 615"),
  ("Cracow", "Poland", "769 498"),
  ("Paris", "France", "2 206 488"),
  ("Villeneuve-Loubet", "France", "15 020"),
  ("Pittsburgh PA", "United States", "302 407"),
  ("Chicago IL", "United States", "2 716 000"),
  ("Milwaukee WI", "United States", "595 351"),
  ("Vilnius", "Lithuania", "580 020"),
  ("Stockholm", "Sweden", "972 647"),
  ("Goteborg", "Sweden", "580 020")
).toDF("name", "country", "population")
println("Input:")
inputDf.show(false)
```

My solution was:

```
 val topPopulation = inputDf
  //        .select("name", "country", "population")
  .withColumn("population", regexp_replace($"population", " ", "").cast("Integer"))

  //      .agg(max($"population").alias(("population")))
  //        .withColumn("population", regexp_replace($"population", " ", "").cast("Integer"))
  //        .withColumn("country", $"country")
  //        .withColumn("name", $"name")
  //          .cast("Integer")
  .groupBy("country")
  .agg(
    max("population").alias("population")
  )
  .orderBy($"population".desc)
//      .orderBy("max(population)")
topPopulation
```

But i have troubke, because "Except can only be performed on tables with the same number of columns, but the first table has 2 columns and the second table has 3 columns;;
"

Input:

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------+
|name             |country      |population|
+-----------------+-------------+----------+
|Warsaw           |Poland       |1 764 615 |
|Cracow           |Poland       |769 498   |
|Paris            |France       |2 206 488 |
|Villeneuve-Loubet|France       |15 020    |
|Pittsburgh PA    |United States|302 407   |
|Chicago IL       |United States|2 716 000 |
|Milwaukee WI     |United States|595 351   |
|Vilnius          |Lithuania    |580 020   |
|Stockholm        |Sweden       |972 647   |
|Goteborg         |Sweden       |580 020   |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+
```

Expected:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+
|name      |country      |population|
+----------+-------------+----------+
|Warsaw    |Poland       |1 764 615 |
|Paris     |France       |2 206 488 |
|Chicago IL|United States|2 716 000 |
|Vilnius   |Lithuania    |580 020   |
|Stockholm |Sweden       |972 647   |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Actual:

```
+-------------+----------+
|country      |population|
+-------------+----------+
|United States|2716000   |
|France       |2206488   |
|Poland       |1764615   |
|Sweden       |972647    |
|Lithuania    |580020    |
+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

### Load the test data

```scala
  val inputDf = Seq(
      ("Warsaw", "Poland", "1 764 615"),
      ("Cracow", "Poland", "769 498"),
      ("Paris", "France", "2 206 488"),
      ("Villeneuve-Loubet", "France", "15 020"),
      ("Pittsburgh PA", "United States", "302 407"),
      ("Chicago IL", "United States", "2 716 000"),
      ("Milwaukee WI", "United States", "595 351"),
      ("Vilnius", "Lithuania", "580 020"),
      ("Stockholm", "Sweden", "972 647"),
      ("Goteborg", "Sweden", "580 020")
    ).toDF("name", "country", "population")
    println("Input:")
    inputDf.show(false)
    /**
      * Input:
      * +-----------------+-------------+----------+
      * |name             |country      |population|
      * +-----------------+-------------+----------+
      * |Warsaw           |Poland       |1 764 615 |
      * |Cracow           |Poland       |769 498   |
      * |Paris            |France       |2 206 488 |
      * |Villeneuve-Loubet|France       |15 020    |
      * |Pittsburgh PA    |United States|302 407   |
      * |Chicago IL       |United States|2 716 000 |
      * |Milwaukee WI     |United States|595 351   |
      * |Vilnius          |Lithuania    |580 020   |
      * |Stockholm        |Sweden       |972 647   |
      * |Goteborg         |Sweden       |580 020   |
      * +-----------------+-------------+----------+
      */
```

### find the city in the country having max population

```scala
    val topPopulation = inputDf
      .withColumn("population", regexp_replace($"population", " ", "").cast("Integer"))
      .withColumn("population_name", struct($"population", $"name"))
      .groupBy("country")
      .agg(max("population_name").as("population_name"))
      .selectExpr("country", "population_name.*")
    topPopulation.show(false)
    topPopulation.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-------------+----------+----------+
      * |country      |population|name      |
      * +-------------+----------+----------+
      * |France       |2206488   |Paris     |
      * |Poland       |1764615   |Warsaw    |
      * |Lithuania    |580020    |Vilnius   |
      * |Sweden       |972647    |Stockholm |
      * |United States|2716000   |Chicago IL|
      * +-------------+----------+----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- country: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- population: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: I tried, but i have error: Error:(192, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
    topPopulation.printSchema()

Comment: i just add the code under "find the city in the country having max population"

Comment: you are calling all the function on `Unit`. see if there is `show()` or `printSchema()` at the end while creating `inputDF`

Comment: @rabbit, does this answer helps :)